# Rails3: Where should I put shared custom validation code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have this tiny bit of code, used in a few model classes in an application:

```
validates_format_of :month, :with => /\d{4}\/(0[1-9]|1[0-2])/i, :message => "must be in the format YYYY/MM"
```

What's the rails way to DRY this up? i.e., where should the code go and how should it be called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Active Model Validator](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validator.html)

Comment: This isn't really what I was looking for. But I'll accept for lack of a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [observer in rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers)
to DRY up your code.